# SQL Server Select Get Single Row From Another Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Needing some help with SQL Server select query here.

I have the following tables defined:

UserSource

```
UserSourceID ID Name Dept SourceID
1            1  John AAAA 1
2            1  John AAAA 2
3            2  Nena BBBB 1
4            2  Nena BBBB 2
5            3  Gord AAAA 2
6            3  Gord AAAA 1
7            4  Stan CCCC 3
```

Source

```
SourceID Description RankOrder
1        FromHR      1
2        FromTemp    2
3        Others      3
```

Need to join both tables and select only the row where the rank is the smallest. Such that the resulting row would be:

```
UserSourceID ID Name Dept SourceID Description RankOrder
1            1  John AAAA 1        FromHR      1
3            2  Nena BBBB 1        FromHR      1
6            3  Gord AAAA 1        FromHR      1
7            4  Stan CCCC 3        Others      3
```

TIA.

Edit:

Here's what I have come up so far, but I seem to be missing something:

```
WITH
TableA AS(
SELECT 1 AS UserSourceID, 1 AS ID, 'John' AS [Name], 'AAAA' as [Dept], 1 as SourceID
UNION SELECT 2, 1, 'John', 'AAAA', 2
UNION SELECT 3, 2, 'Nena', 'BBBB', 1
UNION SELECT 4, 2, 'Nena', 'BBBB', 2
UNION SELECT 5, 3, 'Gord', 'AAAA', 2
UNION SELECT 6, 3, 'Gord', 'AAAA', 1
UNION SELECT 7, 4, 'Stan', 'DDDD', 3)
,
TableB AS(
SELECT 1 as SourceID, 'FromHR' as [Description], 1 as RankOrder
UNION SELECT 2, 'FromTemp', 2
UNION SELECT 3, 'Others', 3
)

SELECT DISTINCT tblA.*, tblB.SourceID, tblB.Description
FROM TableB tblB
JOIN TableA tblA ON tblA.SourceID = tblB.SourceID
LEFT JOIN TableB b2 ON b2.SourceID = tblB.SourceID
AND B2.RankOrder < tblB.RankOrder
WHERE B2.SourceID IS NULL
```

UPDATE:
I scanned the tables and there might be some variations of data. I have updated the data for the question as above.

Practically, I need to join these two tables, and be able to only select the row which would have the least RankOrder. In case of record UserSourceID = 7, that particular record would be selected because there's only one row that exists after the tables have been joined.

Comment: Can you show some SQL attempts that you have made?

Comment: Is the rank order 'smallest value' always going to be '1' ? You could just put in `WHERE RankOrder = 1`. There is also the `MIN()` function - [See Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179916.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I use windowed aggregates for this type of solution pretty regularly.  `ROW_NUMBER` will order and number the rows based on the `PARTITION` and `ORDER` you specify in the `OVER` clause.

```
select  UserSoruceID
        , ID
        , Name
        , Dept
        , SourceID
        , Description
        , RankOrder
FROM    (SELECT  UserSoruceID
                , ID
                , Name
                , Dept
                , u.SourceID
                , Description
                , RankOrder
                , ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY RankOrder) ranknum
        FROM    UserSource u
         INNER JOIN
                Source s
               on s.SourceID = u.SourceID ) a
WHERE   ranknum = 1
```

So in this case, for every `ID`, number the rows based on `RankOrder`, and then filter where so you only view the first row.

Here's a helpful link to that function from Microsoft. [ROW_NUMBER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

----UPDATE----

Here's with Rank and Row Number as options.

```
select  UserSoruceID
        , ID
        , Name
        , Dept
        , SourceID
        , Description
        , RankOrder
FROM    (SELECT  UserSoruceID
                , ID
                , Name
                , Dept
                , u.SourceID
                , Description
                , RankOrder
                , ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY RankOrder) row_num
                , RANK() over(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY RankOrder) rank_num --use this if you want to see the duplicate records
        FROM    UserSource u
         INNER JOIN
                Source s
               on s.SourceID = u.SourceID ) a
WHERE   row_num = 1 --rank_num = 1
```

Replace row_num with rank_num to view any items with duplicate RankOrder entries

Comment: You may want to note that if there's a tie for `RankOrder` only one is chosen. It's unclear from data and the requirement *row where the rank is the smallest* if that's really what the OP wants. It may be `RANK()` instead.

Comment: RankOrder will always be unique (and in this case, the least one should be selected). I will check on this answer.